# What are the options to implement a Groupon like system?

Tags: e-commerce, credit-card, groupon

I like to build a system that will allow users to "commit buy" a deal, but will only be charged after a minimum # of committers are reached. The time span in which the "deal" will continue can be either weekly or monthly.

I like to stay away from building one from the ground up as much as possible.

I know there's another thread on StackOverflow that asked paypal, amazon, or google checkout API to serve this purpose, but this seems too much like a hack?

I did some reading on using a gateway like Authorize.net to process credit card information and they can store the user information and has a service like pay-as-you-go. Would using their API be a better choice? Can their pay-as-you-go method provide the system that I'm looking for?

Comment: Why do you consider the usage of Google Checkout, Paypal etc. being a hack? Not sure what you want to achieve...

Comment: well, we will have to do something like charge them $0 to validate the card and there's a time limit of 3 to 30 days? Basically we're using the system that's design for a particular use and trying to work a way around it.

Comment: It's not at all clear what it is that you're trying to do. Explain the payment model (without referring to Groupon) and people may be able to suggest something.

Answer (score 1):

> I did some reading on using a gateway like Authorize.net to process
>   credit card information and they can store the user information and
>   has a service like pay-as-you-go. Would using their API be a better
>   choice?

I have used Authorize.net for recurring payments and it is easy to implement if you are fluent in working with a web service (regardless of language). You can integrate with them without the user needing to leave your website and without storing the user's credit card information.

However, you will be receiving the user's credit card number to implement such a model, and there are still precautions to be taken (versus redirecting to a secure third party site to receive the number).

**Refine your question to be more specific to receive more specific answers.**

Comment: Integrating them in my site and storing the credit card information is what I want, but I also want to charge them only when a minimum number of committed buyers are reached. Can I do that with Authorize.net?

Comment: @user1120565 - you can do one-time charges with Authorize.net, but you would have to call them directly and ask if they have any tools like that. Chances are, you would have to manage most of the logic on your end. If you design is to store credit card numbers, make sure you are fully PCI compliant: https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/